# Escape Character to xml conversion

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, escaping, xml-serialization

My requirement is like

Input :-

`<request>
    <attribute>
    <attributeName>Name</attributeName>
    <attributeValue>a &amp; b</attributeValue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
    <attributeName>Name1</attributeName>
    <attributeValue>b</attributeValue>
    </attribute>
    </request>`

Output:-

`<request>
    <attribute>
    <attributeName>Name</attributeName>
    <attributeValue>a & b</attributeValue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
    <attributeName>Name1</attributeName>
    <attributeValue>b</attributeValue>
    </attribute>
    </request>`

Escape characters can come in n number of tags and i need to replace all at run time as attribute element type is unbounded.
How can i achieve the same in xslt???

Comment: The required output is not well-formed. You cannot have unescaped ampersand characters in XML.

Comment: Sorry @mzjn, but I have to disagree with you. `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&]]></xsl:text>`

Comment: @NickG: Sure, you can escape the character using a CDATA section. But the wanted output given in the question has a naked ampersand, which makes it ill-formed.

Comment: @NickG Yes, that will "work" - except the output is not XML.

Comment: Yes you're 100% right. The output that @user3384223 requires is not well-formed XML. Fortunately, user3384223 doesn't require well formed XML (judging by the output example).

Comment: More likely, the OP is unaware that the output will be unusable as XML. So "helping" them is not really helping (IMHO)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the output you want! (Let me know if it doesn't!)

The **identity** template, copies all elements.

The **ampText** template, looks for all text containing `&amp;`

The **letters** template iterates (recursively) over all letters in the text, and replaces all instances of `&amp;` with `&`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template name="identity" match="* | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @* | text()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ampText" match="text()[contains(.,'&amp;')]">
    <xsl:call-template name="letters">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="letters">
  <xsl:param name="text" select="'Some text'" />
  <xsl:if test="$text != ''">
    <xsl:variable name="letter" select="substring($text, 1, 1)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$letter = '&amp;'">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&]]></xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$letter" /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:call-template name="letters">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $letter)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, It worked. Thanks everyone for your kind and best responses.